# how to check if a TCP port is available in c socket?

Tags: c, sockets

i am writing a program that 2 players wants to connect to the server to play rock, paper and scissors.The first player connects to the port 60000 and when the second player want to connect it tries to connect to port 60000. if it fails, it will connect to port 60001. At this moment i am not sure how to implement the second player.

Client:

```
int sock = 0;
char *hostname = "127.0.0.1";
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
char buffer[1024] = {0};
if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
{
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
    return -1;
}

memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;


// Clear this field; sin_zero is used for padding for the struct.
memset(&(serv_addr.sin_zero), 0, 8);
// Lookup host IP address.
struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(hostname);
if (hp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unknown host %s\n", hostname);
    exit(1);
}
serv_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *) hp->h_addr);

serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);


if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
    return -1;
}

//getting the user name
printf("please enter your name:");
scanf("%s",buffer);
send(sock , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );

//initializing the game
read( sock , buffer, 1024);

//playing the game until the user enters e  
do{
    printf("%s",buffer);
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    scanf("%s",buffer);
    while(check_input(buffer)==0){
        printf("wrong input,try again:");
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        scanf("%s",buffer);
    }
    send(sock , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );//sending the input to the server
    printf("client:sent %s\n",buffer);
    read( sock , buffer, 1024);
    printf("client:received %s\n",buffer);
}while(is_over(buffer)==2);
return 0;
```

in server:

```
char player1Name[1024];
char player2Name[1024];
int p1_score = 0;
int p2_score = 0;
char buffer[1024] = {0};
int server_fd;
int server_fd2;
int player1_socket;
int player2_socket;
struct sockaddr_in player1;
struct sockaddr_in player2;
int opt = 1;
int opt2=1;
int player1len = sizeof(player1);
int player2len = sizeof(player2);

// Creating socket file descriptor for player 1
if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0){
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// Creating socket file descriptor for player 2
if ((server_fd2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0){
    perror("socket failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// making the first socket reusable
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,&opt, sizeof(opt))){
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// making the second socket reusable
if (setsockopt(server_fd2, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,&opt2, sizeof(opt2))){
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//specifying the address of the first player
player1.sin_family = AF_INET;
player1.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
player1.sin_port = htons( PORT1 );

//specifying the address of the second player
player2.sin_family = AF_INET;
player2.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
player2.sin_port = htons( PORT2 );

// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 6000
if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&player1, sizeof(player1))<0){
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


if (listen(server_fd, 1) < 0){
    perror("listen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


if ((player1_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&player1,(socklen_t*)&player1len))<0){
    perror("accept");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

get_playerName(player1Name,&player1_socket);

// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 6001
if (bind(server_fd2, (struct sockaddr *)&player2, sizeof(player2))<0){
    perror("bind failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


if (listen(server_fd2, 1) < 0){
    perror("listen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


if ((player2_socket = accept(server_fd2, (struct sockaddr *)&player2,(socklen_t*)&player2len))<0){
    perror("accept");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

get_playerName(player2Name,&player2_socket);
char input1;
char input2;
do{
        input1=get_nextMoves(player1Name,buffer,&player1_socket);
        printf("%c\n",input1);
        input2=get_nextMoves(player2Name,buffer,&player2_socket);
        printf("%c\n",input2);
        evaluate(input1,input2,&p1_score,&p2_score);
}while(input1!='e' && input2!='e');
strcpy(buffer,result(1,p1_score,p2_score));
send(player1_socket , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );
strcpy(buffer,result(2,p1_score,p2_score));
send(player2_socket , buffer , strlen(buffer) , 0 );
return 0;
```

At this moment, i am running this code for both the player 1 and player 2 for the sake of experiment.When i run player 2 code, it just get stuck.
I was hoping for an error(EADDRINUSE more specifically).What is going on? how can i go further with my code?

Comment: if anyone need anything else from me, let me know

Comment: please help ASAP

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].  Post an MCVE and we might be able to help you.  As it is, you don't even tell us which code path is executing.  Have you tried stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: Why are they connecting to different ports? Clients have to connect to the same port that the server is listening on. Why would the server listen on different ports?

Comment: Are you thinking that only one client can connect to a port at a time? Everyone connects to port 80 on www.google.com.

Comment: this is my school project, i have to private as possible. sorry. I don't want to be accused of academic dishonesty

Comment: based on the project description we have create 2 seperate sockets in the server

Comment: The less code you show us, the more we have to write ourselves. That's MORE dishonest.

Comment: that's why i have to use different ports

Comment: The server is listening on 2 ports, 6000 for player 1, 6001 for player 2?

Comment: true.I am here for learning anyways

Comment: yes that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for you to get an error, the server has to close the socket that's listening on port 6000 when the first client connects. Otherwise, your connection will succeed, but hang because the server doesn't call `accept()` a second time.

If the server does this, then the second client should get the error `ECONNREFUSED`, and it can try the second port.

```
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
{
    if (errno == ECONNREFUSED) {
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT + 1);
        if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        {
            printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
            return -1;
        }
    } else {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this has a potential failure mode due to a timing window. If both clients try to connect at about the same time, the second client's connection request might arrive before the server has closed the listening socket, so the call to `connect()` will still succeed, even though the server never processes that connection.

The solution to that requires a more elaborate server design, where it accepts the second connection and returns a response saying that the port is already being used. Although if it could do this, you wouldn't need two ports in the first place.

Comment: thanks for the response, i do call the accept the second time in the second socket that i created but i can't close the first socket since i want to get input from both clients at the same time

Comment: Closing the listening socket has no effect on the accepted socket.

Comment: oooh nevermind,Thank you so much. i forgot my own code for a second.